# Virtual machine of android with added samsung os layer?

Tags: samsung, virtualization

Is there a way to run a virtual machine of android like in avd, or in genymotion, but with added os layer that samsung adds in their phones? Also emulating the usb ports that the phone have when you plug into the computer.

I'm asking this, because their docking software, kies only runs with samsung phones stock roms, and i'm working with that.